# Where can I find a model trained to detect patterns of an object like laboratory mice?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow, pattern-recognition

I am working on a real-time pose detection project using a model trained by DeepLabCut, which utilizes .pb and .yaml files for the model. My aim is to find a model or method that can help me detect behavioral patterns in the subjects being analyzed. For instance, I would like to apply an unsupervised learning algorithm that can identify and return the most frequent behavioral patterns (such as the most repeated poses) in the behavior of a particular subject, like a rat. Is there any recommended approach or method to achieve this?
It should be noted that I am working on developing a system that does behavioral pattern detection with python and models trained in DeepLabCut.
I have been thinking if TensorFlow and OpenCV can be a tool.

Thank you so much for giving me some ideas!!!